# Stuck at Grub2 Prompt

Tags: boot, windows, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have Windows XP installed in my system. For some work, I downloaded an ISO of the light version of Kali on a separate internal hard disk partition (G:) and installed Grub2 on the same drive to boot it from there (I had not yet booted Kali)

Now when I restart my computer, I get stuck at the Grub2 prompt and unable to do anything from here.

I would like to boot into my installed Windows and remove the Grub Bootloader. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Edit: My disk drive is corrupted. Any methods relying on this won't be of much help.

Comment: [GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot) may help.  Also, using the images in that question, please describe the *grub2* prompt on your system, (*i.e.* does it say *"grub_rescue"*, or is it some other prompt).

Comment: It shows just grub›

Comment: I saw that, and it might have helped if I had a Linux system installed. But I have only Windows installed. So I can't boot into any Linux system like they say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert your Windows XP USB or PXE and boot it
2. Open the recovery console
3. Type: fdisk /mbr
4. Reboot

In recovery console, other options include:
Type 'help' for the commands that the RC can run.

- Try 'fixboot'. This re-writes the boot record.
- Try 'fixmbr'; again, this may damage a partition table that it doesn't understand, so be wary of taking this step... you may want to use this as a last resort and only if you have a single partition on the disk.

src: https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Windows-Recovery-Console-from-XP-CD

Comment: Same question. Do I get to keep my data or does it format the system?

Comment: Hello Yuzuriha Inori, No it will not delete your data. its repairing your grub master boot record which just is a tiny 1mb partition that says, go to your data on a different partition.

Comment: Just one more thing. Can you please update the answer in favour of an USB boot rather than CD? I have a damaged CD drive, but can boot using a pd

Comment: If you dont have a USB. you might need to PXE, the easiest solution is Cobbler.

Comment: What are CD drives? USB is the only method I use if I dont have a PXE, (I have a home PXE ;) )

Comment: You wrote a CD in your answer :)

Comment: PXE = install over network FYI and requires some advance and patients, might get something fast with docker.

Comment: Nice screendump guide for more advanced troubleshooting FYI: https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Windows-Recovery-Console-from-XP-CD

Comment: no problem, remember, if your messing around with multiboot and grubs, backup your data first, easier and less hassle. Always VirtualBox for free linux OS on your machine without messing with partitions and once you install the VB tools, it works very well. My personal choice is VMware, their tools run the smoothest.

Comment: I actually made a restore point before this. But can't access that.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Windows XP installation media and press R at the "Welcome" screen to get into Recovery Console. Then use the `fixmbr` command to overwrite Grub2 with the standard Windows MBR code.

Comment: Would that format my system? I mean, would it delete my data? :|

Comment: No, it only rewrites the MBR boot code. The partition table will be unmodified, and so all your partitions will be safe.

Comment: If you are concerned so much about your XP drive contents, you can use Linux live CD to run `dd` and store an image of the entire drive elsewhere. Then you can play and if something goes wrong, revert by re-imaging your drive from backup. But the methods already given to you are non destructive and you should be fine as  long as Windows recovery works as expected. Read any prompt and confirmation carefully before you take actions!