# GNU GRUB on boot

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, grub

I kali linux 2018, when I started up kali linux a grub terminal showed up, I don't know why is it happening, can anyone explain? and what should you suggest me to do now? I have tried methods on internet but no use. Picture attached.

I've tried using the method in "[GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot)" but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much! [image: grub]

[image: grub>exit]

When i exit grub this shows up, and apparently i have ubuntu installed too?

Comment: More information please! Are you running a LiveCD? Have you installed it? Dual Boot? Single Boot? Did you check verify the MD5? Where did you install Grub?

Comment: @arochester I deleted my whole harddrive and then installed linux, yes it's single boot and I didn't get last two questions of yours.

Comment: Did you read this?  https://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install

Comment: @arochester yes i followed it

Comment: @JeffSchaller ;-;

Comment: @dsstorefile1 i get it it now. Just wanna know the answer now

Comment: What "_methods on [the] internet_" did you try? What happened? What should have happened? Specifics please.

Comment: @roaima methods like https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot&ved=2ahUKEwi76_rFyonbAhXMvxQKHZGuBnEQjjgwC3oECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3WxGgegDLHQZih1zeF2oNs

Comment: Please add these methods to your question where it's easy for everyone to find.

Comment: Please type three commands: `ls (hd0,gpt1)`, `ls (hd0,gpt2)`, and `ls (hd0,gpt3)` to the GRUB prompt and add the description of the responses you get for each command to your question. If the response is just one line of text, don't attach a screenshot, just copy the text.

Comment: @telcoM it says (hd0,gpt1): filesystem is fat. (hd0,gpt2): filesystem is ext2. (hd0,gpt3): filesystem is unknown.

Comment: I'm assuming your name is not Kali Linux 2018. So let say you have tried to install Kali Linux. Don't install it if you don't have a serious linux background or install it as a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to use another install media.(dvd, or cdrom)
"failure reading sector 0x0 from cd0" means sector address 0x0 is corrupted.
I think the sector address 0x0 is a boot block.

thanks

Comment: No, Kali is installed but the DVD isn't in the drive so nothing can be read from it.

Comment: This might be an artifact of the UEFI firmware. Traditional BIOS presented a CD drive without loading any drivers first only when the CD drive was actually in use for that particular boot attempt. UEFI may present them all the time, even when there is no disc inserted in the CD drive.