# Dual boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu - can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot

I try to dual boot Dell Inspiron 5405 which Windows 10 has already installed with Ubuntu. At this moment, **I stuck on GNU GRUB when I'm trying to boot Ubuntu**. Here's a steps which I done:

1. Disabled secure boot from BIOS.
2. Created a live USB with bootable Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu alongside to Windows 10 on the same SSD (the latest version of Ubuntu and Rufus tool).
3. I also ran 'try mode Ubuntu' and used Repair Boot Tools. Here's a raport: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SDnNtV5mMy/

Of course, I found solution like this - [GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot/330852#330852) - but I can't see 'grub' folder in any partitions.

What should I do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You do not show Ubuntu installed, but do have Ubuntu boot entries in UEFI that would be from an install? Did you delete ext4 partition with Ubuntu? Or were you installing to an external drive not now plugged in? Only other drive shown is the live installer.

Comment: @oldfred First - thanks for your answer! No, I didn't delete any ext4 partitions, any files and so on. I just installed Ubuntu on my SSD using live USB, that's all. In boot manager (clicking F12 on Dell logo) I can choose between two options - Ubuntu and Windows Boot Manager so it's seems like I have Ubuntu but something go wrong.

Comment: The entries stay in UEFI boot menu, your f12 until you manually delete them, even if you uninstall Ubuntu. So that only means you have Ubuntu if that entry works, which it does not look like it will.

Answer (score 0):

Hey There i Think that this link should help you.
Good Luck, Ash.

[Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Along with Windows 10](https://www.linuxtechi.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-20-04-lts-along-with-windows-10/)