# Opensuse loads to grub command line after restart

Tags: grub, opensuse

I have restarted my computer and now Opensuse does not load, instead it goes to grub.

I have `grub 2.06` and `opensuse 14.1`.

I have been trying to follow [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot) answer but cannot get it working with opensuse.

I run the following:

```
ls
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

Then,

```
ls (hd0,1)/
efi/
```

...

```
ls (hd0,1)/efi
./ ../ boot/ opensuse/
```

...

```
    ls (hd0,1)/efi/boot
./ ../ bootx64.efi fallback.efi MokManager.efi
```

...

```
    ls (hd0,1)/efi/opensuse
./ ../ MokManager.efi grub.efi shim.efi boot.csv grub.cfg grubx64.efi
```

When I run (changing `(hd0,1)`, to `(hd0, 2)`

```
ls (hd0, 2)
dev/ rub/ selinux/ lib/ sbin/ srv/ usr/ opt/ .Trash-0/ lib64/ .snapshots/ home/ etc/ var/ tmp/ sys/ mnt/ root/
```

How can I fix the boot problem?

Answer (score 0):

As taken from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Using_the_command_shell

Try the following steps instead:

```
set root=(hd0,2)
linux (hd0,1)/vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda1
initrd (hd0,1)/initramfs-linux.img
boot
```

Comment: On the second line, it says `/vmlinuz-linux` not found.

Comment: prepend a /boot/ before that