# GRUB starts in command line/terminal mode

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, pop-os

I tried everything already, including all the solutions from this post (which present exactly the problem I'm facing) : [GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot)

I also reinstalled everything, and ran Repair Grub, but none of these fix permanently the problem.

To boot I have to go to the Boot Selection menu by pressing keys at startup. This is not really convenient.

Here's my Boot Info summary: http://sprunge.us/pTV3Qp

I'm on Pop OS, dual booting with Windows 11
If you need more information, feel free to ask.

I'm sincerely desesperate and I'm sorry to give you so little information, and I hope you'll be able to help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two EFI system partitions (ESP) nvme0n1p1 (Windows, a bit of grub) and nvme0n1p4 (grub, systemd-boot, not sure where all these Pop_OS-d5deea39... files are coming from). The "pop" (grub) entry starts in rescue mode? What about the other "Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS" (systemd-boot) entry, does it work? And how do you boot into Pop OS? Ideally you should only use nvme0n1p1 as ESP.

Comment: @Freddy the "pop" entry starts also in command line but not rescue mode. To be fair I don't really know what it is, but I know that even when my grub worked, if I chose "pop" to boot it would enter command line mode.
What do you mean by "how do you boot into Pop OS?" ?

Comment: @Freddy I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/hbzCSjlbInY

Comment: I had this issue with Vanilla Debian on my Raspberry Pi. I had to fix this by compiling GRUB from source code.